# proposition statements in logic

Tags: logic

So I'm learning logic and proof and I'm just starting to do proposition sentences. So from my understanding it's a statement that is true. So for example.

Number 1 is a proposition statement, the rest aren't? Thanks

1)2+3 = 5

2)A banana is larger than its skin

3)London is the capital or Paris

4)Answer this question

5)5 + 7 = 10

Comment: A proposition is *either* true *or* false. Note that it has to have a true or false value, it can't be ambiguous. From this, can you figure out which are proprositions?

Comment: Right so numbers 1, 2 and 5 are a propositions?

Comment: Numbers are numbers. Propositions are statements, sentences, which have truth values (true, false). All except 4) are propositions.

Comment: London is the capital or Paris is a propositions? But that doesn't have a true or false value.

Comment: @SearchingFor yes it does. It is false. Number $2$ is a bit ambiguous. If you interpret it as "All bananas are larger than their skins", then it is a proposition. If you interpret it as "There is some banana larger than its skin", it is also a proposition, but a different proposition.

Comment: One should make super clear the definition of a proposition in math and philosophy are NOT IDENTICAL. A proposition in philosophy is a concept and not a physical entity like a sentence. To say a proposition is a sentence is wrong as me saying a unicorn is a horse with a built in horn on its forehead. Notice a unicorn is also a concept and not real--just as propositions are not sense verifiable.

Answer (score -1):

A proposition is a statement which as a whole statement may be interpreted as either true or false. In the smallest state the things which are either true or false are called relations.

1) and 5) are proposition since we have the $=$ relation which relate the term $2+3$ to the term $5$ and $5+7$ to the term $10$. Note that when the question is wether the statements are proposition sentences we do not care if it should be true or false just that an evaluation is possible.

2) Contain a relation LargerThan which relate a banana to a banana skin, this may be true or false, thus a sentence.

4) is not a sentence since we may not say wether "answer this question" is true or false.

3) is a bit tricky it depends on how we look at it. We may either see it as the sentence say that London is the capital and say nothing about Paris. In this case it is not a propositional sentence as then the word "Paris" is not involved in any true or false evaluation. On the other hand we may interpret it as 3) say that London or Paris is the capital in which case the statement say something about both London and Paris which may be true or false.
As it stands though I would say that 1,2 and 5 are the only propositions.